# What video recording software supports screen recording from virtual cameras on OS X on M1 Mac?

Tags: macos

I've got a M1 Mac Mini running the latest MacOS (11.12.23) and want to record camera video for youtube videos via Iriun or other virtual webcam software, as the webcams currently available are of inferior quality as opposed to my iPhone 12 camera IMO and I don't really want to purchase a DSLR or mirrorless camera.

When I go into quicktime there is no option to use the virtual camera input, however Zoom and Discord both support it. So my question is what other 3rd party screen recorders also support virtual camera input on MacOS?